# Handle invalid xml character while serializing

Tags: java, xml

I have requirement where I need to serialize a document which contains a string like `ﾝￊￒ%ﾝￋ&amp;`. While serializing it throws the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: The character '' is an invalid XML character
```

Is there a way we can serialize this String as is with any workaround?

```
StringWriter stringOut = new StringWriter();
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
Element rootElement = doc.createElement("company");
doc.appendChild(rootElement);
String xml = "ﾝￊￒ%ﾝￋ&amp;";
//String xml = "ﾝￊￒ%ﾝￋ&amp;";
Element junk = doc.createElement("replyToQ");
junk.appendChild(doc.createCDATASection(xml));
//junk.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(stripNonValidXMLCharacters(xml)));
rootElement.appendChild(junk);

//org.w3c.dom.Document doc = this.toDOM();

//Serialize DOM
OutputFormat    format  = new OutputFormat(doc,"UTF-8",true);
format.setIndenting(false);
format.setLineSeparator("");
format.setPreserveSpace(true);
format.setOmitXMLDeclaration(false);

XMLSerializer    serial = new XMLSerializer( stringOut, format );
// As a DOM Serializer
serial.asDOMSerializer();

serial.serialize( doc.getDocumentElement() );
```

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: You could attempt different encoding instead of UTF-8. There's a list here you could try: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_2022#ISO.2FIEC_2022_character_sets.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I read your question as a deserialisation question, not serialization. Sorry.

The answer is that you need to escape them using Uuicode entity escape strings.

Character `ﾝ` becomes `&#12477;`. See [Japanese Katakana chart](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/japanesechartkatakana.html)

Also see here [XML Escaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping)

---

You need to pre-process the file to correctly escape the xml characters.

1. read each character in the file
2. if the character is invalid xml, [escape it appropriately](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml%28java.lang.String%29)
3. write character to temporary file
4. at the end of the original file, overwrite original with temporary file.

Your file is now valid xml and can be parsed by standard means. It will most likely be bigger. Give the supplier of your file a telling off for writing a buggy xml writer ;)

Comment: There is no way to serialize that character. Please note if I open that xml in internet explorer, I am able to see that correctly. That means xml containing such character is a valid xml file but why it is throwing invalid xml character while serializing it.

Comment: The above comment does not look like a question, rewriting it. My question is there must be some way where we can serialize there characters, because I have written these character in an xml file and opened that xml file with Internet explorer and it worked fine. It displayed the xml. If these were invalid xml characters then why Internet Explorer could display it.

Comment: @Abhishek "There is no way to serialize that character" - are you sure? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping ALso, there are unicode entities for katakana characters http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/japanesechartkatakana.html. Is it katakana? I have no way or being sure.

Comment: How can we escape it, I have used String xml = "ﾝￊￒ%ﾝￋ\\&amp;"; in the above code but still it throws the same exception.

Comment: Character ﾝ becomes &#12477 is not a problem and this character is being serialized correctly. I further debugged and found that in that string, 0x00000019 character is a problem (I am not able to copy paste that character here). This character is just before &amp; in this string ﾝￊￒ%ﾝￋ&amp;  (if you type this string in eclipse you should be able to see that character. Its like question mark in a box.)